Compose Lazy Column is very Laggy while scrolling
In my compose Application I have a simple list with LazyColumn but I'm facing a lag when I scrolling specially at first
In my list I have a image loading and had some conditions but I remove those conditions and still has the lag
I got release version and added key to my list and my model has stable
@Composable
fun TestScreen(marketList: List<CombineMarketResponse>? = null) {

LazyColumn (Modifier.background(Color.White )){
    if (marketList != null) {
        items(marketList , key = {it.id}) {
            MarketListItem(market = it  ) {

            }
        }
    }
}

and this is MarketListItem
@Composable
fun MarketListItem(market: CombineMarketResponse, onMarketClick: (CombineMarketResponse) -> Unit) {
val context = LocalContext.current
val painter =
    rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        model =
        ImageRequest.Builder(context).data(imageUrl)
            .decoderFactory(SvgDecoder.Factory())
            .crossfade(true)
            .decoderFactory(SvgDecoder.Factory())
            .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
            .placeholder(if (needPlaceHolder) AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_placeholder) else null)
            .error(if (needPlaceHolder) AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_placeholder) else null).build(),
    )

Column(modifier = Modifier.clickable(indication = null, interactionSource = remember {
    MutableInteractionSource()
}, onClick = {
    onMarketClick(market)
})) {
    Row(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.size_12))
            .height(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.size_44)),
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .fillMaxHeight(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart
        ) {
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .background(
                        color = colorRedSell,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(6.dp)
                    )
                    .padding(
                        vertical = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.size_3),
                        horizontal = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.size_12)
                    )
                    .widthIn(min = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.size_32)),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            ) {
                BodyText(
                    text = "321",
                    fontFamily = RabexFont.SemiBoldFaNum,
                    fontSize = RabexFontSize.Body3,
                    color = Color.White,
                    style = TextStyle(textDirection = TextDirection.Ltr),
                )
            }
        }
        Column(
            Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(top = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.size_2))
                .fillMaxHeight(),
        ) {
            BodyText(
                text ="12",
                fontFamily = RabexFont.RegularFaNum,
                fontSize = RabexFontSize.Body3,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.size_6)))
            BodyText(
                text ="12",
                fontFamily = RabexFont.RegularFaNum,
                fontSize = RabexFontSize.Body4,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            )
        }
        Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End, modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
            Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                BodyText(
                    text = "${market.base}/${market.quote}",
                    fontFamily = RabexFont.RegularFaNum,
                    fontSize = RabexFontSize.Body4,
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.size_4)))

                Image(
                    painter = painter,
                    contentDescription = "Coil Image",
                    modifier = modifier,
                    colorFilter =
                    if (imageColor != null) {
                        ColorFilter.tint(color = colorPrimary100)
                    } else {
                        null
                    },
                )
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.size_6)))
            Row {
                     Box(
                        modifier =
                        Modifier
                            .background(
                                color = colorSecondary100,
                                shape = RoundedCornerShape(6.dp),
                            )
                            .padding(
                                horizontal =
                                dimensionResource(
                                    id = R.dimen.size_6,
                                ),
                                vertical = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.size_2),
                            ),
                    ) {
                        BodyText(
                            text = stringResource(id = R.string.p2p_trade),
                            fontFamily = RabexFont.RegularFaNum,
                            fontSize = RabexFontSize.Body5,
                            color = colorNatural6,
                        )
                    }
                 Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.size_4)))
                     Box(
                        modifier =
                        Modifier
                            .background(
                                color = colorSecondary100,
                                shape = RoundedCornerShape(6.dp),
                            )
                            .padding(
                                horizontal =
                                dimensionResource(
                                    id = R.dimen.size_6,
                                ),
                                vertical = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.size_2),
                            ),
                    ) {
                        BodyText(
                            text = stringResource(id = R.string.title_trade_exchange),
                            fontFamily = RabexFont.RegularFaNum,
                            fontSize = RabexFontSize.Body5,
                            color = colorNatural6,
                        )
                    }
             }
        }
    }
    Divider(thickness = 1.dp, color = colorSecondary100)
}

}

Please replace your code with a [mre] so we can try it out ourselves. Make sure it is executable and exhibits the problem you describe.

Try it in release mode, the debug mode will always lag
